# How has God destroyed the wisdom of the wise?

Tags: science

In 1 Corinthians 1:19, Paul writes:

> [1 Corinthians 1:19-20](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20corinthians%201:19&version=KJV)
>
> For it is written, I will destroy the wisdom of the wise, and will bring to nothing the understanding of the prudent. Where is the wise? where is the scribe? where is the disputer of this world? hath not God made foolish the wisdom of this world?

How has God destroyed the wisdom of the wise and made foolish the wisdom of the world?

Ironically, much of the world seems to think that science has done the same to God.

Comment: This is a good example why higher education is important. While the translation is rather pretty, confusing people for all eternity with poor technical wring is not good.

Comment: St. Athanasius's great book *On the Incarnation* treats this fairly thoroughly.

Comment: Oh no, [a whole book has been written about it](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paul explains what he means when read in context.

> I Corinthians 1:18-27 For the preaching of the cross is to them that
>   perish foolishness; but unto us which are saved it is the power of
>   God. For it is written, I will destroy the wisdom of the wise, and
>   will bring to nothing the understanding of the prudent. Where is the
>   wise? where is the scribe? where is the disputer of this world? hath
>   not God made foolish the wisdom of this world? **For after that in the
>   wisdom of God the world by wisdom knew not God, it pleased God by the
>   foolishness of preaching to save them that believe.** For the Jews
>   require a sign, and **the Greeks seek after wisdom: But we preach
>   Christ crucified, unto the Jews a stumblingblock, and unto the Greeks
>   foolishness; But unto them which are called, both Jews and Greeks,
>   Christ the power of God, and the wisdom of God.** **Because the
>   foolishness of God is wiser than men; and the weakness of God is
>   stronger than men.** For ye see your calling, brethren, how that **not
>   many wise men after the flesh, not many mighty, not many noble, are
>   called**: But **God hath chosen the foolish things of the world to
>   confound the wise; and God hath chosen the weak things of the world to
>   confound the things which are mighty;**

In other words, the world believes that 'Christ crucified' is foolishness, when it is in fact the wisdom of God. By their wisdom (their learning and reasoning) they reject the wisdom of God, which is so simple that it confounds supposedly learned men.

The scribes, being the few that could actually read the Old Testament scrolls, should have been the ones to recognize Jesus. But instead it was simple fishermen (not many noble, not many wise) that recognized who He was.

Paul's point is that the approach to God is not found through intellectual reasoning and man's wisdom, but **God is revealed in such simplicity that the wise of the world stumble**.

Answer (score 0):

**How has God destroyed the wisdom of the wise?**

This "destruction" is pretty much only discernible to those who are "of the truth".

> John 18:37  Pilate therefore said unto him, Art thou a king then?
>   Jesus answered, Thou sayest that I am a king. To this end was I born,
>   and for this cause came I into the world, that I should bear witness
>   unto the truth. Every one that is of the truth heareth my voice.

When man was able to receive the indwelling Holy Spirit, he was able to see through many of the lies and deceptions Satan has foisted upon the world;

> 1 Corinthians 2:14  But the natural man receiveth not the things of
>   the Spirit of God: for they are foolishness unto him: neither can he
>   know them, because they are spiritually discerned.
>
> 1 Corinthians 1:18  For the preaching of the cross is to them that
>   perish foolishness; but unto us which are saved it is the power of
>   God.

The so-called "science" of this age has been diverted to serve as a sort of substitute "truth". It is used to bully people into submission by the power of arrogance and self-appointed authority.

A Christian may be told the an unborn child is only a lump of tissue that can be discarded at will, but knows via the Spirit of truth that this is not true and killing children is wrong.

A Christian may be told that smart people have decided that evolution is true and the there is no God, but have the living God inside of him telling him that rumors of his death have been greatly exaggerated.

A Christian may be told that having the government run everything is the ideal form of society, but think that 16 trillion dollars of debt may not be the most secure foundation on which to build and collectivism only seems to bring slavery.

Satan rules this world (for now and insofar as he is allowed by God).

> Ephesians 2:2  Wherein in time past ye walked according to the course
>   of this world, according to the prince of the power of the air, the
>   spirit that now worketh in the children of disobedience:
>
> 2 Corinthians 2:11  that we may not be over-reached by the Adversary,
>   for of his devices we are not ignorant.

The "wisdom" of the wise has been destroyed by the penetrating light brought by the Spirit of truth.

> Ephesians 5:8  for ye were once darkness, and now light in the Lord;
>   as children of light walk ye,

Comment: Wait are you saying Christians have always been libertarians? Throughout history Christians have had such a variety of political and theological beliefs that I find it strange when, say, Protestants claim that Catholics aren't Christians. Do they really imagine Real Christianity (TM) took off after the reformation, and before then maybe 5 guys were actually saved? Or how people say the inquision and earlier Church weren't real Christians because we disagree with their activities. Then who was?